# increase text box size bootstrap (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to increase the size (length) of textboxes in a horizontal form?

```html
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the `col-md-*` classes but it hasn't worked.

Comment: try putting it on the textbox it self

Comment: remove your cookies cltrl+F5 then check it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative way to do this is to just change the col-md-x class on the div that wraps your textbox and validation message to your desired width.

For example, change this:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

And now your textbox will be the 5 column width instead of 10.  This requires no extra classes and an added bonus is that if you have a longer validation message, it will wrap within the same space as your textbox.

Answer (score 10):

All answers were helpful.

My sollution was to change the default max-width in my css cause it was restricting the size

```
input, select, textarea {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Then changing the col-md-* class worked fine.

thanks

Comment: I modified this for mine to just:

`max-width: unset;`

Answer (score 3):

I'd add a class to your textbox:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control long-textbox" })
```

Then style it in your CSS:

```
.long-textbox{
    width:300px;
}
```

You can use the size attribute, but I feel this is more of a stylistic thing and should be managed in CSS.

Comment: Wish I'd called my class `long-textbox` now, then we'd be almost identical haha!

Answer (score 3):

usually your  tag has a max-width field set. If you change it as

```
text {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

then you can achieve the full available width. If you are making this for multiple device resolutions, then it would be better to use percentage width rather than using the fixed width in px. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 3, the `form-control` class sets `input` elements to be 100% of the container.

Alternatively you can manually apply your own style:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "wide-control" })
```

With CSS like this:

```
input.wide-control {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML INPUT "Size" property.

Example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", size="15" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Other, new { @class = "form-control", size="25" })
```

Comment: HTML **size** attribute is deprecated.

Comment: Where can i find this info please? Are you sure INPUT size is deprecated?

Comment: You are correct **input size** is still valid. These days, a lot front-end designer/developer use **width** in CSS for **input** to consistent across all controls in all browsers. Anyhow, I take it back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a textbox and use the style attribute along with the **new** keyword as the example shows below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Detail, new { style = "width:600px" })
```

It can also be used for LabelFor

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Detail, "Detail", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4", style = "width:160px" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I allways try to stay away from changing the size, I let things fill the space and use the Grid System.

This helps it work on all screen sizes.

Thanks

http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZczWMsNk9arscbY26j8?p=preview

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Wide</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="**form-control**"  type="TextBox"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Not as Wide</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control"  type="TextBox"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Narrow</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control"  type="TextBox"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, put the size on the textbox input itself. No need to create a new class to handle the width.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
...
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" })
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The BEST SOLUTION**

in MVC C# project go to: *Content folder > site.css*

And change ***max-width*** in css style for ***input select textarea***

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**IT WILL WORK **